# Merge files without duplicates in Visual Studio Community; C#, ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**1. Summarizing the problem**

I'm developing an application that should be able to receive 02 text files sent by the user and then merge them into one, removing all the duplicates. The problem: Tales needs to reconcile the company's bank statement with the inflows and outflows she recorded in last month's Excel. For this, an OFX-type file is used, which contains the bank record of all entries and exits for a period and is easy to export through Bankline.

The main problem is that Tales downloaded two OFX files: one that contains trades from the 1st to the 20th and the other which contains trades from the 15th to the 31st.

And now he doesn't know what to do to ensure that all transactions are matched correctly, as the OFX files have transactions from a common period.

**2. Describe what you’ve tried**

So far, I've been able to implement the following code that allows me to receive 2 files from the user and merge them into one, but I haven't been able to implement duplicate removal:

```
using AuvoTech.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;

namespace AuvoTech.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //Define uma instância de IHostingEnvironment
        IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;
        //Injeta a instância no construtor para poder usar os recursos
        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _appEnvironment = env;
        }

        //Retorna a View Index.cshtml que será o formulário para
        //selecionar os arquivos a serem enviados 
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }

        //método para enviar os arquivos usando a interface IFormFile
        public async Task<IActionResult> EnviarArquivo(List<IFormFile> arquivos)
        {
            //INICIO DO TRATAMENTO DE ARQUIVO

            //Verifica se foi enviado algum arquivo
            if (arquivos.Count == 0)
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = "Error: Arquivo(s) não selecionado(s)";
                return View(ViewData);
            }         

            // VERIFICA SE OS ARQUIVOS ENVIADOS SEGUEM OS PADROES EXIGIDOS PELO APLICATIVO
            foreach (var arquivo in arquivos)
            {
                //verifica se existem arquivos vazios e alerta o usuario. Necessario (?)
                if (arquivo == null || arquivo.Length == 0)
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = $"Aviso: Voce importou um arquivo vazio {arquivo.FileName}.";
                    return View(ViewData);
                }

                //Verifica e restringe o tipo de arquivo enviado
                if (!arquivo.FileName.Contains(".ofx"))
                {
                    ViewData["Error"] = "Aviso: Arquivo Não Suportado. Somente arquivos do tipo '.ofx' são aceitos na aplicação. Tente novamente.";
                    return View(ViewData);
                }

                //Criacao de variaveis e Armazenamento dos Arquivos
                //var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "email", "EmailRegister.htm");
                string wwwRoot  = _appEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                string fileDb   = "\\Arquivos\\";
                string fileDest = "\\Recebidos\\";
                string fileName = arquivo.FileName.ToString();
                string fullPath = wwwRoot + fileDb + fileDest + fileName;

                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await arquivo.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                string readFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fullPath);

                ViewData["Read"] = $"{readFile}";
            }

            //FINAL
            //Mostra a leitura dos arquivos .OFX removendo as transacoes repetidas 
            ViewData["Resultado"] = $"Falta fazer isso pra terminar o desafio";
            return View(ViewData);
        }
    }
}
```

**3. When appropriate, show some code**

After a lot of reading, I was able to find a ready-made solution in the Microsoft docs but i am not able to make it work as i would like. (Eg at [docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-combine-and-compare-string-collections-linq))

```
    // Concatenate and remove duplicate names based on  
    // default string comparer.  
    IEnumerable<string> uniqueNamesQuery =  
        fileA.Union(fileB).OrderBy(s => s);  
    OutputQueryResults(uniqueNamesQuery, "Union removes duplicate names:");  

    // Find the names that occur in both files (based on  
    // default string comparer).  
    IEnumerable<string> commonNamesQuery =  
        fileA.Intersect(fileB);  
    OutputQueryResults(commonNamesQuery, "Merge based on intersect:");
```

So... can anyone help me with tips or advice?

Comment: "...not able to make it work as I would like..."? What exactly do you want the method to do? What does it do? Some sample data and actual and expected output would be very useful here to clarify the desired situation.

Comment: I dont know how to put all the source file at stackoverflow. The live test can be found in github.com/talesvalente/auvotech

Comment: i'm stucked at duplicate removal... The output shows only fileA + fileB full merged

Comment: I couldn't find any sample data at github.com/talesvalente/auvotech

Comment: Sorry @ChristopherHamkins , I didn't commit to the branch because I couldn't reproduce what I'd like. This is the last thing i tried:

           var stream1 = new FileStream($"{_appEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Files\\Received\\extrato1.ofx", FileMode.Open);
            var stream2 = new FileStream($"{_appEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Files\\Receveid\\extrato2.ofx", FileMode.Open);

ViewData["Result"] = $"{stream1} {stream2}";
return View(ViewData);

**RESULTS**
System.IO.FileStream System.IO.FileStream

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.